# Free/Open Source GUI designer with xml output that could be customized (screensize, widgets)?

Tags: user-interface, designer, mqx

we are developing GUI using eGUI under MQX RTOS (ARM Cortex M4). Instead of hardcoding widgets, callbacks etc on each screen we would like to use a tool to desing GUI screens graphically, then generate XML description file that could serve as a basis for GUI code generator (as a second part of a tool).

QTDesigner is something very like that, but cannot be customized to another, custom set o widgets. So we're looking for any GUI designer that could offer options for customization (at least screen size and widgets set) and produce xml output file with description of desing.

Then we can develop code generator out of this xml file...

Any idea, pointer, advice ?

Thanks in advance,

Bule.

Comment: Have found the tool that is pretty close to what I'm looking for : ResourceEditorGUI_2.0.0 from STM32. What I would add is to have configurable properties of graphic objects...

Answer (score 0):

Pencil's native file format is based on XML.

http://pencil.evolus.vn/

This is nowhere near *ideal*, but with the right scripting (Ruby and Nokogiri for instance) you could convert the pencil file in to a more cleaned up and direct XML file, which you then use in a separate step to generate GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, most GUI Designers are closely tied with their widget toolkits. Qt Designer -> Qt, Glade -> GTK+, wxFormBuilder -> wxWidgets. Customizing a different designer to your library is not [easy](https://github.com/littlevgl/lvgl/issues/601). The best option is to choose a GUI library that comes with a designer. The [two main](https://community.nxp.com/thread/368665) pre-supported graphics libraries for MQX RTOS are [eGUI](https://github.com/NXPmicro/eGUI) and [PEG](https://www.nxp.com/design/software/embedded-software/peg-graphics-software:PEG-HOME). Only the PEG Graphics Library has a GUI designer and the only free version (for NXP Silicon only) is [PEG-Lite](https://www.nxp.com/design/software/embedded-software/peg-graphics-software/peg-lite-runtime:PEGLT).   If you're using STM32 hardware, it's probably best to use [TouchGFX](https://www.touchgfx.com/) which has a designer and is free for STM32 devices only.

[TotalCross](https://totalcross.com/) have developed a [tool](https://yourapp.totalcross.com/knowcode-app) that converts Android XML built by Android Studio's Layout Editor to their Java API that runs on TotalCross VM. It's all explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7o3p14wQPsE). The tool has not been officially released on their product page but it's on [GitHub](https://github.com/TotalCross/KnowCodeXML). Here is a [list](https://medium.com/@kevmuhuri/top-five-libraries-for-creating-gui-on-embedded-linux-5ce03903be32) of GUI libraries for embedded. Half of them have GUI designers.